# Set path of dynamically loaded module in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, load, python-module

OK, so this will be a little tricky to explan well. I will try my best.

So consider my naive implementation of "load python module by filename" as follows:

```
def load_module_by_filepath(module_name, module_filepath):
    module=None
    failure=None
    try:
        spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, module_filepath)
        module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
        spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    except Exception as e:
        failure=f"Import of module '{module_name}'from file '{module_filepath}' had errors ({e})"
        module=None
    return module, failure
```

Let's say I have the following code in a file **my_mod.py**:

```
from my_other_mod import something

def somefunc():
    something()
```

Then I load it using my loader like this:

```
module, failure = load_module_by_filepath('my_mod', 'my_mod.py')
```

At this point I will be able to call **somefunc** from my loaded module like so:

```
my_callable = getattr(module, 'somefunc')

my_callable()
```

All good, except, if you look carefully there is an import statement in **my_mod.py** for **something** from **my_other_mod**.

So what happens when I run this code is that I get a failure to load the module saying "No module 'my_other_mod'".

I am guessing this is because **my_other_mod** was installed in a location that is not available to my newly loaded module. They don't belong to the same environment or context if you will.

*So my question is, how can I change my loader to add **my_other_mod** to the path of **my_mod** so that it will load and run?*

Comment: Can you `sys.path.append(path_to_missing_module)` ?

Comment: You mean from inside the loaded module? Although I can control what is in the loaded module I would really not want it to care how it was loaded, so let's say for curiosity's sake that I could not change it!